# Need to assign variables from nested array object

Tags: php, json

I am sure I am missing something simple here but am having trouble grabbing values from an object that contains several nested arrays.

Here is the object being assigned:

```
  $obj = json_decode($uri); // Convert JSON
```

Here is the print_r from this object:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 1 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [coordinates] => Array ( [0] => -88.359306 [1] => 41.685747 ) [country_id] => US [state_id] => IL [address_locality] => Oswego [address_text] => 201Washington St [street_number] => 201 [street_name] => Washington St [confidence] => 0.71 [county_id] => 17093 [_type] => geo.place [geo_geometry_type] => Point ) ) ) )
```

I am having trouble getting at the values for county_id, coordinates, etc...

I was trying to use something like $obj->results[0]->coordinates[0].... but this didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just missing the `[0]` after $obj?

```
$obj[0]->results[0]->coordinates[0]
```

Comment: Yep your exactly right, lol I figured it was something obvious. Time for more coffee! Thanks so much for the helP!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$obj[0]->results[0]->coordinates[0] ect...
```